# Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'users' wen I execute ban command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

The bot gives me an error if the user turned off his/her DMs. How do I ignore this error and ban the user anyway?

**My Code:**

```py
@commands.command()
async def ban(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":no_entry_sign: Error.", description="**I can't ban Moderators.**", color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)        
    elif ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
        if reason is None:
            await member.send("You was banned from *server*")
            await member.ban(reason=None, delete_message_days=0)
        else:
            await member.send("You was banned from *server*")
            await member.ban(reason=reason, delete_message_days=0)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":no_entry_sign: Error.", description="**You are not a Moderator.**", color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Error:**

> Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'users'

Comment: Nothing in your code has anything that could throw a KeyError. Please read up on a producing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please paste the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your issue is that you are sending a DM to the banned users, and it throws an exception when you send that DM if the user has their dm's off, the solution is to not DM that user. As far as determining if the user can be DM'ed, I don't think there is a built-in way for it, so you could simply use try-except.